# What Am I Riddle 4?

Tags: riddle

> I move faster in certain solids, but slower in certain gases.
>
> I am typically broken by objects with large masses.
>
> I can be used as for pleasure, practice.
>
> If used excessively, I can cause harm.

```
What am I?
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are

> **sound**.

I move faster in certain solids, but slower in certain gases.

> Sound moves faster in solids and slower in gases.

I am typically broken by objects with large masses.

> The sound *barrier* can be broken by large aircraft.

I can be used as for pleasure, practice.

> Music is pleasing to the ears, and the playing of musical instruments may be practiced.

If used excessively, I can cause harm.

> Excessive exposure to loud sound can cause hearing loss.

Comment: I feel like small masses would be more common for objects breaking this...